# Getting token from a context in Next js

Tags: javascript, next.js13, conditional-operator, hydration

I'm encountering this error in my Next.js application:

`Error: Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server.`

Inside my Navbar component, there's an li tag that is rendered conditionally based on whether the user is logged in or not. I suspect this line is causing the error because removing it resolves the issue. How can I perform this conditional rendering without triggering the error?

```
const token = cookies.token;
const usuario = cookies.usuario;
```

```
<ul className="navbar-nav">    
  <li className="nav-item">
    <a href="/about" className="link">About us</a>
   </li>
   <li className="nav-item">
      <a href="/about" className="link">Team</a>
   </li>
   <li className="nav-item">
      <a href="/about" className="link">Articles</a>
   </li>
{token ? (
    <li className="nav-item">
        <a href="/about" className="link">Hello, {usuario.nome}</a>
       </a>
    </li>
) : null}
</ul>
```

EDIT: Actually, now I've discovered that the error occurs when I try to retrieve cookies.token and cookies.usuario from the context. I'm using useContext from React. I've attempted to use useEffect, but it's not retrieving the values

```
const { cookies } = useContext(AuthContext);
```

```
    var token = "";

    var userData = { nome: "" };

    useEffect(() => {
        token = cookies.AdvWebsite;
        userData = cookies.UserData;
    }, []);
```

EDIT: I also attempted to use states instead of vars, but the username did not update to display on the screen. I could resolve this issue importing dynamic from "next/dynamic" in the file and exported the function as follows:

```
export default dynamic (() => Promise.resolve(Navbar), {ssr: false})
```

Answer (score 0):

First it would informative to see how does the `cookies` resolve. Another thing, you might try to assign a state variable for the token and just get the cookie value using a React hook as `useEffect`, when the page loads.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I already edited my question. I tried to use the useEffect hook but now it's not getting the cookies and displaying the "login" button.

Comment: You should add `cookies` into the `useEffect` dependency array, so it would trigger the effect after getting the data. Also, I would suggest to use state hooks `useState` for token and user data, because it is not recommended to declare them as `var`. The reasons: what if your user data or token changes and you want your component react to that.

Comment: I also tried using states instead of vars, it worked, but upon logging in, the navbar component did not update the username for display on the screen. I could resolve  adding 
 import dynamic from "next/dynamic";
and 
export default dynamic(() => Promise.resolve(Navbar), {ssr: false}); 
to the file